# VPN access to office not seeing some folders in AD "Home Folder"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, windows-10

I am running Server 2008 R2 and I am using the Active Directory Home Holder to set each user a Private Folder that only they can access, it also contains their Documents, Music and Pictures which all sync okay, but one user on Windows 10 is unable to Access the Private Folder within the Home Folder, this is just a standard folder with permissions for only that user, It all works in the office but not remote on VPN, she can see the folder but it wont open

If I copy the folder to my Home Folder I can access it without issue, when the user clicks on the folder they get an error "Location is not available - This file is currently not available for use on this computer"

Also manually mapped drives do not appear on VPN but work okay in the office

I have enabled slow connection via GPO as I thought this was a slow connection problem and it was using offline mode

The VPN is also setup on GPO

The user vpn logon is set to use Windows logon, so automatically connects them when the select vpn access, shared drives are accessible, one other user reported that when they open the shared drive the folders are empty?

I am based remote from the office so physically seeing the laptop in question is not easy

How can I trace the problem, it seems that it is something to do with slow connection, but I am at a loss to how to solve it

Comment: Check the network location of the VPN network adapter to confirm if it is Public, Private, or Domain.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a DNS error, please check the DNS setting from those computer. A mapped driver of like servername\ can not work if the DNS/DNS suffix is set incorrectly.

Be sure the VPN adapter set the correct DNS, and it's used for those address resolution.